# NotFoundAction.IGNORE workaround issue

Tags: hibernate

I found @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE) should trigger eager load and hit performance issue for our project. After google, Using the following method instead of above hibernate setting. but I hit another problem about this workaround method.

```
public Person getPerson() {
    if (!Hibernate.isInitialized(person)) {
        try {
            Hibernate.initialize(person);
        } catch (org.hibernate.ObjectNotFoundException one) {
            person= null;
        }
    }
    return person;
}
```

The problem is at our DAO , the result set is a List , and at that list we have two record point to the same Person proxy. Then, when the first record call the getPerson is ok. return null, the second record call the getPerson it will return the proxy instead of null. because it have initialize before.